Getting the name of the current application on macOS Swift
I’m working on a menubar extra, and I would like to fetch the name of the current application. I have the following code:
var app: NSRunningApplication = NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication!
var bundleIdentifier: String = app.bundleIdentifier!
var name: String = app.localizedName!
var icon: NSImage? = app.icon

The code mostly works, but in a few cases, the localizedName property is an empty string. The other properties aare fine.
I can’t find any other property which has the application name. One such application is SQLPro for SQLite which is a legitmate App Store application. It clearly has name which appears in all the right places except as above.
Is there an alternative way of getting the application name?
A Possible Solution
Thanks to @Sweeper, I’ve got something that works:
let bundle: Bundle = Bundle(url: app.bundleURL!)!
let appName: String = app.localizedName!.isEmpty ? bundle.infoDictionary!["CFBundleName"]! as! String : app.localizedName!


Can you give an example that is free?

@Sweeper Do you mean a free application?

Yes. A free app that exhibits this issue.

@Sweeper I’ve just tried to find another app, including a few that I wrote in Electron and Python, and nothing else behaves this way. It might be a one-off. However, I would have thought that the app name must be somewhere else, since it shows up on the dock, the menu bar and the application switcher.

Try creating a Bundle from app.bundleURL and get its Info.plist keys. Does CFBundleName and CFBundleDisplayName have any values?

@Sweeper OK that works. I’ve added some code in my question, though it’s probably a bit clumsy. Thanks
